# File from email on phone to computer

Tags: email, data-transfer, file-transfer

I have a large .mdb file attached to an email which I can only access on my phone, as it's being blocked by webmail on my home computer. I need to get it to my computer but when I try to forward the email the attachment is removed. I can't download it to my phone because it's too large. I've tried uploading it to Google Drive via my phone but it takes too long and times out.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of phone? Any other cloud solution (e.g. Dropbox) you could use? Or do you have access to another computer somewhere?

Comment: Also what kind of email address/server is it? Perhaps there's an option that will allow it to show in webmail.

Comment: Have you tried AirDrop?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with patrix, use open in dropbox from the mail.

Or, to file handling app like FileBrowser and then rename the extension to .txt and mail it to your web email.

Dropbox seems far easier.